# How to associate values to keys without blocking GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection

**My question is: How can I associate a bunch of values with a bunch of keys**

- without modifying the keys directly, and
- without preventing the keys from getting GC'd (knowing that the values have strong references to the keys)

**Background:**

I need to associate a bunch of complex objects (call them the values) with a few particular objects (call them the keys).

Normally, the way I'd do this is to use a hashmap that associates keys and values.

This works great.  However, I also need to ensure that the mappings don't interfere with garbage collecting of the keys.  In other words, the presence of a mapping should not prevent the key from getting garbage collected.

Normally the way to solve this is to use a WeakHashMap, which only holds WeakReferences to the keys.  However, WeakHashMaps will only work if the values in the map do not have strong references to the keys.  Unfortunately, my values all have strong references to my keys, which prevents the keys from getting garbage collected.  This can be worked around by using weak references on values as well, but that's not a viable solution because I can't allow my values to be GC'd before my keys.  As long as the key object still exists, the values must also exist.

So my typical solution to this situation is to stop using a HashMap and to instead modify the key to have strong references to all the values that it needs.  This will ensure that I can still get all the values for a given key, but won't prevent the key from getting GC'd when it's natural lifecycle is done.

Unfortunately, I can't modify the keys, so I can't add the values directly to the keys.  So what other clever solutions are there?

Answer (score 2):

Given the constraints:

- The keys have *some* sort of reference to the values
- The values have strong references to the keys
- Don't prevent the keys from getting GC'd
- Values cannot be GC'd before keys
- As long as key for a value exists, that value must also exist
- Values and keys should still be GC-able

...I don't think this is logically possible.

Why can't you remove the value → key mapping (or at least use referentially different but logically `.equal()` objects) and then go with the `WeakHashMap` solution?

Comment: by "remove the value -> key mapping", do you mean remove the strong references that the values have on the keys?  Sadly, I can't modify the values (or rather, I can't prevent a user from putting in values that would have strong references to the keys, and it's highly likely they would do so)

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Unless you're using a singleton/enum/flyweight pattern type for the keys, I still think you should be able to use referentially different but logically equal keys in a `WeakHashMap` to solve this problem.

Comment: What would keep those keys in the map?  Wouldn't they just get GC'd at an arbitrary time?

Comment: Yes, but you posed that solution yourself in the question, but for the fact that the values have strong references to the keys. If that's a deal-breaker than why did you mention it? TBH, it sounds to me like you haven't fully thought out exactly what your criteria _are_. If you want the values to be GC able but not the keys, then use a regular `HashMap<Key, WeakReference<Value>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the solution to your problem is :
1. Maintain weak references to the Keys from your values, so Keys can be Gc'd
2. Use a WeakHashMap to map keys to values (so values do not get GC'd, if there is strong reference to its Key).

Below is a sample application to explain the design i mentioned above :

```
public class WeakApp {

WeakHashMap<Key,Value> weakHashMap = new WeakHashMap<Key,Value> ();
ArrayList <Key> strongReferences = new ArrayList<Key>();

static class Key {
    String smthg = "key";
    public Key(int count) {
        smthg = smthg + count;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return smthg.hashCode();
    }

     protected void finalize() {
         System.out.println("Key object " + smthg + " Gc'd");
     }
}

static class Value {

    static int count = 0;
    WeakReference keyReference = null ;
    String smthgValue = "Value object of key ";

    public Value(Key key) {
        keyReference = new WeakReference(key);
        count++;
        smthgValue = smthgValue + key.smthg;

    }
    protected void finalize() {
         System.out.println(" " + smthgValue + " Gc'd");
     }
}

void initValueToKeys(){
    for(int i =0; i< 10; i ++) {
        Key key = new Key(i);
        strongReferences.add(key);
        Value value = new Value(key);
        weakHashMap.put(key, value);
    }
    System.out.println("Weak hash Map size is " + weakHashMap.size());
}

void doMain() {

    System.gc();
    System.runFinalization();

    //Now slowly remove the strong reference keys simulating them going out of use
    Iterator<Key> itr = strongReferences.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext()){
        Key key = itr.next();
        System.out.println("Removing strong reference to key " + key );
        itr.remove();

    }

    System.gc();
    System.runFinalization();

//shows if any values have references still from keys(should be 0), and expunges stale values to be Gc'd        
    System.out.println("Weak hash Map size is " + weakHashMap.size());

    //give chance for gc to remove the values 
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.gc();
    System.runFinalization();

    System.out.println("System exited");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WeakApp weakApp = new WeakApp();
    weakApp.initValueToKeys();
    weakApp.doMain();
}
```

}

Regards
Austin